# How to set parse ACL to public write?

Tags: swift, parse-server

I am writing an app where I would like to set the ACL for a created object to allow for public writing (there is an issue where deleting the object, which is what I want to do, can only be done if public write is set to true). I have seen several similar questions that have been answered like:

```
let acl = PFACL()
acl.setPublicReadAccess(true)
acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true)
yourObject.ACL = acl
```

However, the `.setPublicWritAccess(bool)` no longer seems to be the correct syntax. I tried to do it similarly with:

```
acl.setWriteAccess(true, for: "Public")
```

but this did not work. Does anyone know how to do this appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Parse's [documentation](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/index.html) it seems that `publicWriteAccess` and `publicReadAccess` are instance properties. So, this should work:

```
let acl = PFACL()
acl.publicReadAccess = true
acl.publicWriteAccess = true
yourObject.ACL = acl
```

See more details [here](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFACL.html#/c:objc(cs)PFACL(py)publicWriteAccess).

Answer (score 1):

As of Parse iOS SDK 1.14.3:

```
let acl = PFACL()
acl.getPublicReadAccess = true
acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
object.ACL = acl
```